# Bash how to edit a variable

Tags: bash

I am new to using bash. Now I am about to read a value, but the output of the console is too long and I just want to shorten it to the specific value.

```
netstat -m

24270/3315/27585 mbufs in use (current/cache/total)
4142/1724/5866/1000000 mbuf clusters in use (current/cache/total/max)
40/1478 mbuf+clusters out of packet secondary zone in use (current/cache)
0/145/145/524288 4k (page size) jumbo clusters in use (current/cache/total/max)
0/0/0/524288 9k jumbo clusters in use (current/cache/total/max)
0/0/0/83968 16k jumbo clusters in use (current/cache/total/max)
...
```

Now I want to get to the 5866 in the second line and wrap it in a variable.
Currently my script looks like this:

```
mbuf_stat=$(netstat -m)
mbuf=$mbuf_stat
mbuf=${mbuf#*)}
mbuf=${mbuf#*/}
mbuf=${mbuf#*/}
mbuf=${mbuf%%/*}
echo "$mbuf"
```

Is there an easier way to do this? It seems pretty complicated to me. Unfortunately, I have not found a simpler way yet.

Comment: You could use `bash` regular expressions to do this kind of parsing, but remember that the primary purpose of `bash` is to run *other programs* to do your actual data processing, not do the processing itself.

Comment: The answers given below are right. But also note that in many cases, the tool (`netstat` in this case) may have some command-line option to provide the output in more parsable/precise manner. My comment may not be relevant in the case of `netstat`, but I am just putting it out here as a note since you are new to shell scripting. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
mbuf=$(netstat -m | grep "mbuf clusters in use" | awk -F/ '{print $3}')
```

The difference with the answer from [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) is that I'm looking for the line, containing "mbuf clusters in use" instead of assuming it's the second one.

Comment: Unnecessary grep: `mbuf=$(netstat -m | awk -F/ '/mbuf clusters in use/ {print $3}')`

Comment: @jordanm: I have the habit of filtering using `grep` and adapting the output using `awk` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` for this:

```
mbuf=$(netstat -m | awk -F'/' 'NR == 2 { print $3; exit }')
```

`-F'/'` makes `/` the field separator. `NR == 2` matches the second line of the file. `print $3` prints the third field, which contains `5866`, then `exit` exits the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ netstat -m | awk -F/ '/mbuf clusters in use/{print $3}' 
5866
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mbuf=$( netstat -m | 
>         
> gawk '$_=$--NF' RS='^$' FS='/[^/]+mbuf[^/]*clusters in use.*$|[/\n]+|$' )
> ```

or

> ```
> mawk -F/ '$!NF=$((NF*=/mbuf[^/]*clusters in use/)^_+NR)'
> ```

```
5866
```